# Is it safe to hash password using SHA-256 and then hash it using slower algorithm?

Tags: postgresql, security, passwords, crypt, password-hash

I am creating application that uses PostgreSQL and I want to hash passwords on the database server. Documentation says `bf` algorithm can't handle passwords longer than 72 characters. Is it safe to hash password using SHA-256 an then hash it using the `bf` algorithm?

I am going to use something like `crypt(sha256_as_hex(password), salt)` (in pseudocode). Is it OK?

Comment: See https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2015/03/security-issue-combining-bcrypt-with.html .
Recommendation: bcrypt(base64(sha256)), and note that the sha256 output should be in its binary form, not its hex-human-readable form.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams, what do you mean whn you say “sha256 output should be in its binary form”? You mean I should not do `bcrypt(base64(sha256_hex(…)))`?

Comment: Yep. For example, for 'password', the resulting base64 should be 44 characters, not 88. Examples here: https://gist.github.com/roycewilliams/e9b8155c5632025cb0e8623e4dda61f3

Comment: With `bf` you probably mean BCrypt? BCrypt can handle longer passwords very well, the thing is, that max 72 characters of the password are taken to build the hash. This is not a problem though, because with 72 characters (or more) you have a password that strong, that brute-forcing is out of question anyway.